# Toggle hide/show <tr> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code to show `<tr>` in my table but with every click, it hides the textbox that must be shown when the button is clicked.

Below is my `jQuery` code to show the textbox:

```
$(function() {
   $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
       $('.td1').show();
   });
});
```

And this is my code in `<table>`:

```
<button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" onclick="toggle();" class="span1">ADD</button>
<tr class="td1" id="td1" style="">  
     <td><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you need to apply `display:none` first before you can make it show and hide

Comment: i have already put a display: none in style but still nothing happened

Comment: in css , you have `.td1{display:none}` ? , also make sure your jquery script is working..

Comment: yes i have .td{display:none} and i also tried the jquery if it is working I test it with alerts and it will works. My problem is everytime i clicked the btnAdd it just like a refresh in my page and not showing the textbox

Comment: @bebebe Did you check my update and the demo there? Compare and see what you're currently missing

Comment: @bebebe you sure it's not a button and not a submit that has a form? coz you describe it as a refreshing effect

Comment: can u show us the full html ?

Comment: thank you guys i have already fixed it. I checked my codes and there just a conflict in my ajax and jquery

 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+'/index.php/datacast_ctr/add',
                        data: {
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('.td1').html(data);
                        }
                 });
          });
      });

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have invalid markup. You need to wrap tr in table.something like this:

```
<button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="span1" >ADD</button>
<table class="td1" style="display: block;" >
<tr id="td1" >  
 <td><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And js would be:

```
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.td1')
    elem.toggle('slow');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zVTLw/1/)**

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried it but not working. It just hide the  "tr" and not show it again when i clicked the btnAdd

Answer (score 4):

It will help you

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        $('.td1').toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="span1">ADD</button>
<table>
<tr class="td1" id="td1" style="">  
<td><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/A7Gsu/)

Comment: i have tried it already but it will just hide the textbox and not toggle back to show the textbox again

Comment: @bebebe Please check my demo

Comment: You are missing `table` tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide your element by default to make `show()` method works:

```
.td1 {
    display: none;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hThWV/)**

or you can use **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** here:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.td1').toggle();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hThWV/1/)**

Comment: thanks for your reply i will try it and comment again for the result :)

Comment: and this one if you want to toggle between show and hide of your input: http://jsfiddle.net/hThWV/1/

Comment: i tried it already but it just like refresh in my page and not toggle the textbox

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` to your click function. Check my update

Answer (score 2):

hope it is help you.

you can see my [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EBowa)

```
  $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
         $('.td1').toggle('show');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button like So:

```
            <td>
                <button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd">ADD</button>
            </td>
```

and Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            $('.td1').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```